# Simple Javascript: Running a function over an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create an array of vertices, and then run the 'rect' function over this array to display an arbitrary amount of rectangles. Right now, I have:

```
var vertices = new Array();

function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 600);
    ...
    iter(width/2 - c/2, height/2 - c/2, c);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
        fill(200);
        rect(vertices[i]);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
function iter(x, y, len) {
    r_1 = random(0, 1);

    if (r_1 < 0.5){
        vertices.push(x, y - len*0.5, len*0.5, len*0.5);
    }
}
```

I have seen lots about using map or foreach to run functions over arrays but I don't know why this doesn't work (specifically, using a for loop to run a function over an array). I am obviously very new to all this stuff! An explanation of what I seem to misunderstand would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: A canvas displaying rectangles described by the data inside the array 'vertices'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
vertices.push(x,y-len*0.5,len*0.5,len*0.5)
```

you're calling `push` with *four* arguments, so *four* items get pushed to the array. Because you're calling `rect` with `verticies[i]` later, it sounds like each item of `verticies` should be a data container of some sort - an array or an object, otherwise the points of each vertex will be separated out over multiple indicies. For example, if you were to use an array:

```
function iter(x, y, len) {
  r_1 = random(0, 1);
  if (r_1 < 0.5){
    vertices.push([x, y - len*0.5, len*0.5, len*0.5]);
  }
}
```

And then *spread* each array in the `vertex` array into the `rect` argument list:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  // ...
  iter(width/2 - c/2, height/2 - c/2, c);
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
    fill(200);
    rect(...vertices[i]);
  }
}
```

This assumes that `rect` is a function that accepts 4 arguments. (you could also change `rect` so that it accepts a single array as an argument instead, and avoid the spread syntax, if you wanted)

You also might consider using an array literal rather than `new Array` - calling the Array constructor is [rarely a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800594/in-javascript-why-is-preferred-over-new-array):

```
var vertices = [];
```

Comment: I should have seen that. Thanks so much!