# querySelector: how not to call function when return is null?

Tags: javascript, function, dom, queryselector, dom-traversal

I need to execute a function on an element that may or may not exist in the DOM, using a `querySelector` (not `querySelectorAll`, because there will be *at most* one such element). The most elegant solution I can devise is:

```
(function (element) {
    if (element) {
        [business logic of the function]
    }
}(document.querySelector([css selector])));
```

The goal would be *not* to call the function at all if the `querySelector` doesn't return an element. (`querySelector` returns `null` if no matching element is found.)

My original question lacked clear criteria, and my objections to the responses resulted in the question being closed as being opinion-based. Here's the criteria:

I want to solve this without having to declare a variable external to the routine, e.g., not:

```
let x = document.querySelector([css selector]);
if (x) {
    [business logic on x]
};
```

I'd like something as elegant as document.querySelectorAll, which returns an iterable NodeList (or null) that does not require testing on the returned data before performing work on it. I.e.,

```
document.querySelectorAll([css selector]).forEach(function (element) {
    [business logic using element]
});
```

`querySelectorAll` is overkill here, because I'll have 1 returned element at most, and if nothing is returned, no business logic will be run.

At present, the only way I can see to do it is: pass the returned value to the function, and check in the function whether the return is not falsy before proceeding with the work of the function.

Is there an elegant way *not* to call the function if the return of the `querySelector` is not an element?

Again, I don't want to use `querySelectorAll`, since there will be at most one element that matches the `querySelector`. The beauty of the current solution is that it relies on an anonymous function, and there's no need to create an explicit variable (with `var` or `let`), since the function provides a param for passing.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: The usual way is with `let element = ...; if (element) ...`

Comment: Depends on the business logic. If it is a single method call on that element you can use `document.querySelector(...)?.someMethod(...)`.

Comment: @Phil he wants it to return null if element not present

Comment: @AfzalK. doesn't say that anywhere in the question

Comment: The goal would be not to call the function at all if the querySelector doesn't return

or am missing something ?

Comment: @Barmar I want not to explicitly define  'elrment'; part of the elegance of the existing code is that "element' is defined automatically within the anonymous function

Comment: @ĐinhCarabus It's not possible to call an anonymous function (or even a previously defined function) on a returned Element, right (using the syntax you've provided, that is)?

Comment: @AfzalK. querySelector() will return null if no matching element is found. I don't want to call the function at all if querySelector() returns null, and without having to define a variable external to the called function.

Comment: @Tom, with optional chaining (`obj?.method()`) it is possible: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining, but of course the method has to be defined on that object.

Comment: @Phil The current code requires an explicit test on 'element' inside the function. The goal is to avoid calling the function at all if the querySelector returns null, and without having to define a variable external to the function. querySelectorAll() does this by the nature of the way it works, but it's overkill provided I'll have at most one matching element.

Comment: @ĐinhCarabus The object will be a returned DOM Element, so it will not have the method on it.

Comment: @Tom, you've never shown us your actual business logic, so I thought I'd point out this possibility.

Comment: @ĐinhCarabus The business logic will be of arbitrary complexity, but never a returned value...always some operation on the returned Element or an operation that requires information from the returned Element.

Comment: Note that querySelectorAll() solves this problem, but it's overkill. With it, you can do `document.querySelectorAll([selector]).forEach((element) => { [business logic] });` If nothing is returned, the function is not invoked. I'm essentially seeking the same kind of elegance for `querySelector`.

Comment: @Tom, I think this looks really goofy but it fulfills your requirement of not using querySelectorAll: `[document.querySelector([selector])].filter(Boolean).forEach(function(element) { [business logic] })` :)

Comment: @ĐinhCarabus Thanks...it does work, but it's not as elegant/short as my starting code.

Comment: @Tom, sure but it is simply impossible to somehow *not invoke* the function expression in an *immediately invoked* function expression.

Comment: @ĐinhCarabus I tried to tag you in my post below, but I couldn't find a way to do that, so I linked to your profile here. Thanks for the excellent suggestion.

Comment: @Tom have you tried `Element.matches` ?

Comment: @AfzalK. for other purposes, but it wouldn't suit this one.

Comment: @Tom well can you re-describe it in more easy way, for now going through half of question i forget the rest or comments confusing me

Comment: @AfzalK. I'm simply trying to pass the returned value of `querySelector` to an anonymous function when the returned value is an `Element`, and not invoke the anonymous function at all if the returned value is `null`. `querySelector` returns `Element` on success or `null` on failure. I also don't want to have to declare the variable that will hold the returned value with `let` or `var`; it should be self-contained. The code I provide in the description is the best I can do, except I have to test for `null` in the called function. I'm seeking a way to do this if the returned value is "truthy".

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to use `querySelectorAll`, since there will be at most one element that matches the selector

You may want to reconsider this stance. This is a perfect use case for `querySelectorAll`: you want to get a collection with *all* the elements in the document that match the selector. If your document contains at most one such element, that's ok, and you'll get a collection of either 0 or 1 elements - that doesn't change the fact that this is just a special case of getting N elements.

Using this approach, the code is short and simple:

```
document.querySelectorAll(…).forEach(element => {
    … // business logic
});
```

or

```
for (const element of document.querySelectorAll(…)) {
    … // business logic
}
```

If it would look weird to have the logic executed multiple times, add a comment to explain that the selector matches either 0 or 1 elements.

---

That said, I don't see anything wrong with

```
(element => {
    if (!element) return;
    … // business logic
})(document.querySelector(…));
```

If you really need a special syntax for this, write your own helper function or have a look at [discussions for some pipeline operators](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pipeline-operator/issues/159), which proposed optional pipelining like

```
document.querySelector(…) ?> (element => {
    … // business logic
});
```

You would need to write your own transpiler plugin or macro for that, though.

Comment: I've used querySelectorAll() as you've described for years, for cases where there will be many matching elements, but I've always cringed when using it for cases where I simply need to grab one element & yet safeguard against the edge case where that element may not exist.  I'd like to use a shorter/distinct routine for cases where I know only one such element should exist; among other benefits, using different routines will therefore be a visual indicator of what the routine is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the variable in the `if` statement.

```
let element;
if (element = document.querySelector("selector")) {
    // do something with element
}
```

Comment: This is shorter, indeed, but I'd like not to have to define 'element' explicitly, though.

Comment: There's nothing better than your solution then.

Comment: Unlike `for`, you can't put the variable declaration directly in the `if` condition.

Comment: @Barmar So `for (let element = document.querySelector("selector"); element; element = null) { … }`? *shudder*

Comment: @Bergi Ugh, that's right up there with `switch(true) { case condition1: ... case condition2: ... }`

Answer (score 0):

The method that [Đinh-carabus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1967864/%C4%90inh-carabus) proposed in the comments above is likely closest to the solution I'm seeking, but only if abstracted into a function that can be called as needed, to wit:

```
function myQuerySelector(selector, func) {
    Array.from(document.querySelector(selector)).filter(Boolean).forEach(func);
}

// trivial use case:
myQuerySelector('body', function (element) {
    console.log(element);
});
```

A less complex solution that could be used without calling an original function would be preferable, but this solution may have general value, so I'm posting it here as a solution.

Comment: Well if you're going to use a helper function anyway, you may as well use a normal `if` statement in there instead of this hard-to-understand syntax.

Comment: Also, at least [use an array literal instead of `new Array`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1800594/1048572)

Comment: heres a more short version: 

`[...document.querySelectorAll('div')].forEach(function(element) { console.log(element); });`

Comment: Afzal K., I want to avoid querySelectorAll() in this case.

Comment: @AfzalK. Also, what you've proposed is the same as `document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(function (element) { console.log(element); });` There's no need to spread the results of `querySelectorAll`, as it returns an iterable nodelist that `.forEach` can be called on directly.